# Vue router update parent component on closing nested routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've the following use-case:

1. Visit `/parent` page and Parent component is rendered
2. Visit `/parent/john` and the Child component is rendered
3. Navigate back to `/parent` the child component is destroyed

At this point I need to update the Parent component. I've the following routes.js:

```
{
  path: '/parent',
  name: 'parent',
  component: Parent,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to, from);
    next();
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: ':child',
      component: Child
    },
  ]
},
```

Since `beforeEnter` the first time the component is rendered **is there any other way to know that the route was updated and trigger a method on the Parent component?**

Comment: Did you take a look at this document? https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: @LucasMarques I did not. That does look good! Mind posting a answer so I can give credit?

Comment: answer added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [reacting-to-params-changes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) may be helpful.

Basically, after registering vue-router all components will have the '$router' and '$route' attributes.

component.$router can be used to bind listeners and change the current route programatically.

component.$route holds the information about the current route.

So, one alternative is watch the '$route' attribute.

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```